# Read from sqlite by only give a set of data and stop

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

My sensor is giving updated data continuously as I can see from the database, SQLite. However, the data I get from it to display is just a set. It stops all after.

```
import sqlite3
import time
import datetime
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from dateutil import parser
from matplotlib import style
style.use('fivethirtyeight')

conn = sqlite3.connect('sqlite2.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def graph_data():
    c.execute('SELECT time, data FROM sensor')
    time = []
    data = []
    for row in c.fetchall():
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        print(row[0])
    

graph_data()
c.close
conn.close()`
```

How do I get continuous live-time data when I print from c.fetchall?

Comment: You have to query repeatedly. A SQL query just returns what's in the database at that moment, there's no live updating.

Comment: First, you probably want to use SELECT MAX(time) FROM sensor; to get an idea about recent sensor updates, rather than querying all rows, or perhaps ORDER BY time DESC, with some LIMIT. Second, it's important to note that while sqlite is terrific it is not a multiuser DB. If an IOT program is INSERTing new rows, and this program is SELECTing them, then it's your job to coordinate the two programs, and not the responsibility of sqlite. (Use postgres or MariaDB if you need the DB to handle that for you.) Verify the IOT part does an immediate COMMIT for each write.